# What is the best way to add edit and delete buttons to a modal?

Tags: html, modal, bootstrap

I have a task data visualization modal, but I need to add an option to edit or delete these tasks. Where in this modal could I insert buttons to delete or edit?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an action button at the bottom. One option would be to expand it to a toolbar with two more buttons (Edit and Delete). You can experiment with the order and the alignment of the buttons (left, center, right); this might also depend on how often users will perform all three actions. The lone button in the center looks a bit off. It looks like you can use the `modal-footer` class for this; see [this example in the Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#modal-components).

Example:

<kbd>✎ Edit</kbd>  <kbd>Delete</kbd>                                                             <kbd>✓ Mark as done</kbd>